# How to display a website's header information in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a way to echo the header information of a webpage, for example:

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
```

etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use the PHP function [headers_list()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php)

Answer (score 1):

[headers_list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) will return the headers of your own webpage in an array. If you want some other servers headers there's a function named [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php). To print it you can either var_dump() it or echo in a foreach.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be [a nice little script](http://www.freewebs.com/phpstatus/) someone wrote for this, complete with all the `if/else if/else` statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the headers as received by the browser, then use something like [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/), [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/), or [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647). All are for Firefox. Personally I use HTTPFox and Firebug the most.

Server-side, you can use [headers_list()](http://php.net/headers_list) as stated earlier, with the proviso it can only show headers that have been set already. If something adds/changes headers later in the script's execution, then you'll be displaying "stale" information.